# Verify order of sequence calls with Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito

I want to verify the order of sequence calls, but it didn't work as I expected.

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.testkit.TestKit
import org.scalatest._
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito

class Test extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem"))
with WordSpecLike
with BeforeAndAfterAll
with PrivateMethodTester
with `enter code here`Mockito
{
  val m = mock[java.util.List[String]]
  m.get(0) returns "one"
  there was two(m).get(2) //do not throw any error, why???
}
```

I'm using
scala 2.11.7,
specs2-core 3.6.6,
specs2-mock 3.6.6,
scalatest 2.2.4

thx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can mix Specs2 and ScalaTest.

You shuld remove `import org.scalatest._` and use `import org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationLike` instead.

```
import akka.testkit.TestKit
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationLike

class Test extends TestKit(ActorSystem("testSystem"))
  with Mockito
  with SpecificationLike
{
  "it" should{
    "raise error" in {
      val m = mock[java.util.List[String]]
      m.get(0) returns "one"
      there was two(m).get(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can see that `sbt test` returns something like.

```
[error]    The mock was not called as expected:
[error]    Wanted but not invoked:
[error]    list.get(2);
[error]    -> at Test$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Test.scala:14)
[error]    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. (Test.scala:14)
```